# Facebook Login not using Instagram_basic permission request

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api

I'm having some issues authenticating my Instagram account and "approving" the right so that the application can use the images from my corporate Instagram account.

Using this documentation to follow our guide: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/getting-started

***Here is what I have completed***:

- An Instagram Business Account or Instagram Creator Account

  - This has been completed and the Instagram account is a business account

---

- A Facebook Page connected to that account

  - This has been completed and linked to the Instagram account (Both the Instagram account and the Facebook page are in our Business Manager panel)

---

- A Facebook Developer account that can perform Tasks on that Page

  - Using my account with all the permissions granted such as (Owner, developer, etc..)

---

- A registered Facebook App with Basic settings configured:

  - All the details have been completed and signed
  - [Business Verification/Supplemental Terms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2y4US.png)

***My Approved Permissions and Features***:
[Approvals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYlnW.png)

***The Facebook Login button is displayed inside our WordPress settings panel***:
[Login Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGRdm.png)

**Problem**:
When I click on the Facebook login button, I only get authenticated to provide my "email address", but instead I need the permissions for Instagram_basic, manage_pages that we're approved.
[Only email is being asked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64o2v.png)

***Code***: In the code, I have the instagram_basic and manage_pages scopes defined.

```
<fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email,instagram_basic,manage_pages" onlogin="checkLoginState();"></fb:login-button>
```

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: So what happens after you click the continue button in the login dialog …?

Comment: can you help to approve my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same, just click continue and there will be another windows which asks you to confirm the access to instagram and the pages you want the app to have access to.

Comment: This worked like a charm! Can't believe I never clicked past the continue button lol.